# A default Hidden grid when toggled(container.show()) doesnt display data unless I sort or resize one of the column

Tags: extjs

I have a grid in a container that is hidden: true by default. 
On a button click - I call container.show() to show the grid -- It shows the grid but doesn't display any data unless I click on sort or re-size one of the column. However, the store seems to be loaded correctly

When the container is set to hidden: false by default - then data on the grid is shown and everything displays fine, toggle works fine.

Do i need to call refresh to the grid on container.show() , if so how. Or could it be something else?

Comment: It would be better to share your tried code rather than explaining. Its so difficult to identify the problem based on explanation.

Comment: Did you make hidden config on grid or container?

Comment: It could be helpful, if you post your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this problem once and the solution had to do with setting the height on the gridpanel inside the container.

```
viewConfig: {
    height:300
}
```